# (object) is a Field but is used like a 'method'

Tags: c#, object, methods, get, field

When running this code i get the error:

**Error 1   'EPSInvoice_ServiceLibrary.EPS_Service.tr_bl' is a 'field' but is used like a 'method'**

It worked fine in VS.net but i'm converting to C#.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Here's the code:

```
public class EPS_Service : IEPS_Service
    {
        List<input_params> Users = new List<input_params>();
        List<token_data> token_data = new List<token_data>(); 
        public decimal cal;
        object tr_bl;
        string branch;


        public void User_Login(input_params inputparams)
        { 
            EPS30Ora.EPS30Svr svr = new EPS30Ora.EPS30Svr();

              if (svr.LogOnEx("EDEESTE", inputparams.VSID, inputparams.Username, inputparams.Password, "EPS30Ora", ref inputparams.ck) == 0)
              {
                  try
                  {
                      Users.Add(inputparams);
                      svr.PrepareByMoney(inputparams.ck, 1, inputparams.meter_number, 10, 0, ref cal);
                      tr_bl = svr.GetInvoiceData(inputparams.ck, svr.Confirm(inputparams.ck));
                      branch = tr_bl(0)(1); 
                      token_data.Add(new token_data() { transfer_number = "0000000" });
                  }
                  catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
                  {

                  }
              }
        }
```

Comment: What is `branch = tr_bl(0)(1);` supposed to do?

Comment: thanks for your reply . here is the definition of GetInvoiceData(): public virtual dynamic GetInvoiceData(string ClientKey, string TrnId)
    Member of EPS30Ora.EPS30SvrClass. I am new to C# and on vb.net it worked fine declaring an object named tr_bl and then retrieving its values with tr_bl(0)(1) for example. GetInvoiceData returns an invoice structrure. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array indexers need to be square brackets:

```
branch = tr_bl[0][1];
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for you reply. When changing to square brackets i get the error: "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'. Do i need to Cast something??? i am stucked. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to cast it to whatever return type `GetInvoiceData()` has. For example, if it is a two-dimensional array of type `int`, you would need to do `branch = (int[][])tr_bl[0][1];`.

Comment: thanks for your reply . here is the definition of GetInvoiceData(): public virtual dynamic GetInvoiceData(string ClientKey, string TrnId)
    Member of EPS30Ora.EPS30SvrClass. I am new to C# and on vb.net it worked fine declaring an object named tr_bl and then retrieving its values with tr_bl(0)(1) for example. GetInvoiceData returns an invoice structrure. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should not define that method as returning `dynamic` unless you really intend to return a dynamic type (even then, it's better to just use `object`). C#, unlike VB, does not use dynamic typing at runtime (except in a few circumstances), so you always need to define the type of what something is otherwise the compiler will complain (as is the case here). You need to figure out what the `GetInvoiceData()` method is actually doing, and what it's actually returning, and then cast to that. `dynamic` is not something that is able to be indexed, you need a type with an indexer, such as an array.

Comment: Thanks SpikeX. GetInvoiceData() is a method from a COM Object referenced in my code. I really dont have access to change anything in the definition of GetInvoiceData. Shall i use something like GetType to get to know what is actually GetInvoiceData returning? Thanks a lot for you help

Comment: Just set a breakpoint in your application in order to debug it and find out what `tr_bl` is. Once you know what it is, you can cast to it, and the array indexers should work.

Comment: hello. i did set the breakpoint and i found that object tr_bl did have all the invoice structure values, for example, for the first field that is invoice number when i select copy expression i get : ((object[])(((object[])(tr_bl))[0]))[0].

Comment: FINALLY, i got the values of the structure casting the object. The breakpoint was helpfull. SpikeX thanks for you help.